# Em CSS, existe alguma maneira de definir o hover inline?

Tags: css, email

Muitas vezes preciso desenvolver templates para envio de e-mails. Porém em alguns casos utilizar a tag `style` para fazer as definições de estilo não funciona. Assim, é  necessário definir os valores estilos para os elementos inline.

Para quem não entende o que é "inline", seria assim:

```html
<div style="background-color: red">
    <h1 style="text-align:left">Olá, mundo</h1>
</div>
```

Sendo assim, se eu precisasse então de fazer um `hover`, que geralmente é feito pela tag `style` ou por um documento css externo, haveria alguma forma de fazê-lo inline?

Sei que é possível fazer com  Javascript, mas provavelmente também seria bloqueado pelo e-mail.

Existe então alguma maneira de definir um `hover`, `active`, `visited` e etc via definição de estilo inline?

Comment: Eu queria responder apenas **não**, mas o site não permite. :p

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Em uma resposta curta, **não tem como**.

Em uma resposta longa, **você não deve**.

`:hover` é um pseudo-seletor e, por CSS, só tem sentido dentro da folha de estilo. Não há qualquer equivalente de estilo inline (uma vez que não está definindo os critérios de seleção).

Tradução [desta resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033166/4843158)

Vale ressaltar que [isso era possível no passado!](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515)

Porém, se você deseja fazer algo parecido, pode usar o `onMouseOver` e o `onMouseOut`.

```html
<a
   href="#"
   onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='#00F'"
>Text</a>
```

Sua pergunta indica que essa opção é para envio de e-mails, ou seja, para adicionar isso em um template que será enviado para um e-mail.

Alguns servidores de e-mails aceitam o `:hover` na folha de estilo, sem ser inline, como você pode ver [como o Gmail.](http://freshinbox.com/blog/interactive-emails-in-gmail-using-css-attribute-selectors/) Porém, isso não é padrão em todos.

Comment: Source (english): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Answer (score 3):

**Não é possível definir regras de pseudo-classes em css inline**. CSS inline pode conter apenas declarações de propriedades. Contudo, no caso específico do hover, você pode utilizar algo semelhante à:

```html
<a href="#" 
   onmouseover = "this.style.textDecoration = 'none'"
   onmouseout  = "this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'">Olá</a>
```

### Referência

[Css pseudo-classes with inline style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)